# Is there way to validate emails without sending confirmation links?

Tags: email

Note : I don't know that this question is most suitable for here or [ux.stackexchange.com](https://ux.stackexchange.com/). Please move it to that site if moderators feel like this is better for that site.

Some(can be said as a lot of too) visitors of one of my client's site uses internet just to get my client service(related to government too). Many of them are created email accounts just for register my client site.

They have no idea about message of "Please check email to complete your registration" after registration and when logging "Your account is not activated yet, please check your email" message.

There are so many non-activated accounts are on database. Some are called(via hotline) to my client and said that there is a message called "Your account is not activated yet, please check your email" when login.

So my client asked that alternative way to verify emails other than sending emails with activate link. Is there any way?

Comment: What specifically do you mean by validate? You will need to be specific about what you consider a "valid" email in this context.

Comment: Sending a link ensures not only that the email address exists, but that it also belongs to the person signing up.    I don't see any way to validate that second part securely without sending an email.   The only possibility would be to piggy-back on somebody else having already done that validation.   For example using Facebook or Google Oauth login.

Comment: Do users need an email address to use this service? (It seems like they don't if you are looking for ways to validate the email without them actually having to check their email - because users seemingly don't know how to use email? In which case, why is email being enforced to begin with?)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that you should adopt a **third party facebook, Twitter or Google login** in your website. By doing this user do not need to verify their email manually since they should have had an email validated by facebook or Google.

For those who have created account already make it in such a way that they could link their facebook/Twitter/Google account to their account and get validated.

This is hardwork though but would pay off.